# EF generated code inheritance

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

What do I need to do in my database if I want my EF generated classes to look like this: 
class A , class B : A , class C : A ?

Currently my DB tables look like this:

1. table A ID PK
2. table B ID PK and FK referencing table A ID
3. table C ID PK and FK referencing table A ID

thanks in advance

Comment: It's not going to magically know to generate classes like that by your database structure. If you are using db first you need to specify your inheritance hierarchy in the model designer.

Comment: Can the person who voted to close explain how this question is not clear? It looks like perfectly clear and reasonable question to me.

Comment: if you are using database first then by using reverse engineering(you can get from nuget) to generate your classes, then you can clear all common properties in B and C and exists in A and let the class B and C to be B:A , C:A respectively and if you are using code first, your classes can easily built the way you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify this when generating your classes. Basically you choose a BaseType in the designer for class B and class C and remove the association. Here is an explanation how to do that (may differ slightly with different versions of EF)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293.aspx

What you want to do is known as "table per type" in case you want to look for more details online.

Comment: Thank you,I used every keyword i could think of with no useful result.